# React-Native-Maps JSON markers example

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Does anyone have a working example of a [react-native-maps] working with JSON feed of the marker locations?

I have the map working with hard coded lat/long markers, but would like to get it populated using JSON.

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example with markers array:

https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/CustomMarkers.js

Tell me if you need more help with this code.

Comment: Thanks for this @eladc :) I did have a read through that example on github. I was hoping to be able to consume a JSON feed of markers to populate onto the map from an API. I think it needs to correspond with a URL and a promise.

Comment: So just include this fetch function in your code:
`
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson.movies;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
`
Taken from here:
[link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Comment: Ah got it, thanks for the link @eladc I didnt see that one before. Much appreciated.